# App Transport Security not working on Distribution

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, app-transport-security

I have set App Transport Security for my iPad App with exception domains for few open api like weather online traffic etc., which we display it in a cordova webview. If I run it directly into iPad, it is working fine. But it is not loading correctly if I archive and distribute it.

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: You don't have a separate Info.plist file for your debug packaging than for production, do you?  There is an info.plist file setting in your project's Build settings.  Also, the NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent is iOS10 only.  Are you distributing via an ad hoc or enterprise profile?

Comment: Enterprise profile

Comment: Have you run deployed the enterprise distribution build on the same device that you did local testing on?  same iOS version?

Comment: I tried on same device and different device.. it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like you are incorrectly adding exception domains.  Don't include http:// in your exception domain entries.

Are you testing locally on an iOS 10 device (which would use the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`to ignore ATS in your web view altogether)? It would work on an iOS 10 device, but maybe the enterprise distribution fails on a device because the device is iOS9, which would try to use your exception domains, which are formatted incorrectly.

Another possible reason for a difference in behavior is that you have a different Info.plist specified for debug vs. release builds.  Verify in your project settings that you are referencing the same Info.plist file for both build configs.

Comment: So if I want to support both iOS9 and iOS10, I shouldn't add NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent is it? Jus list out exception domains.. is that right?

Comment: If you know all the domains that may be accessed in the webview (i.e. users can arbitrarily navigate to sites outside your control), I would stick with exception domains and remove the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` key. Exception domains are supported in both iOS9 and iOS10.   You can add the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`, but it will have no affect on iOS 9 devices.  So if you don't have all your exception domains, the webview will break on iOS 9

Comment: If you need to support both, and can't add exception domains because the user can browse to sites outside your control, you should add both `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`.  In iOS9, it will disable all ATS checks (in webviews and otherwise), but in iOS 10, it will ignore `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` and use the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` key, so any non-webview traffic will still enforce ATS, but webview content will ignore ATS rules.  You will need to provide justification to Apple upon submit (at some point soon)